# Screen tearing when scrolling on Dell XPS 13

Tags: 16.04, dell, screen

When I scroll I get screen tearing, which ends up being a line that runs almost perfectly horizontally from the top-left to bottom-right corners of my screen that distorts whatever flows through it.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I encountered this with Xubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/850225/screen-tearing-in-xubuntu-no-problem-with-ubuntu

Comment: You are a beautiful soul. Worked after a restart :)